# When are JavaScript regular expression literals compiled

Tags: javascript, regex, performance, compilation

According to [MDN's RegExp Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) regular expression literals are compiled while RegExp objects created by calling the constructor are not.

My question is now, when does the compilation take place? As the literal has unique syntax it is identified as a regular expression during parsing. This would make it possible to compile it once and reuse the result every time it gets evaluated resulting in the two examples having (almost) the same speed.

```
var str = "Hello World";

// Example 1
var regExp1 = /[aeiou]+/gi;
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    regExp1.exec(str);

// Example 2
for(var j = 0; j < 1000; ++j)
    /[aeiou]+/gi.exec(str);
```

Any ideas whether this is used in practice by any JavaScript-engine?

Comment: Not sure how you are testing "speed", but there is JSPerf: http://jsperf.com/testing-regexp-define

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Description) clearly state that:

> The literal notation provides compilation of the regular expression when the expression is evaluated.

and

> The constructor of the regular expression object, for example, new RegExp("ab+c"), provides runtime compilation of the regular expression

The test you did are not very clear. Where do you measure performance? This is how I see they should be made:

```
start = new Date();
for(var j = 0; j < 1000000; ++j)
    /[aeiou]+/gi.exec(str);
console.log(new Date - start);

start = new Date();
regex = new RegExp("[aeiou]+", "gi");
for(var j = 0; j < 1000000; ++j)
    regex.exec(str);
console.log(new Date - start);
```

This produces:

```
147
118
```

Clearly, the constructor is faster from my tests (Chrome)

Also in your test you weren't testing the constructor at all. You were just assigning the literal in the first test to a variable name. Basically the tests were identical.

Comment: So an optimization like one-time evaluation and reuse through the parser is unlikely to be implemented as it violates the specification according to MDN.

Comment: On the otherside it seems to be not required at all. I tested with more complex expressions and compilation time is small compared to time required for matching (at least for Firefox 29).
So one can make code more readable by specifying the regexp inside the loop if there are many regexps in use.

Comment: Should also test calling the constructor inside the loop too. You couldn't create the full regex object, but you could parse and compile the regex without producing the actual object for the runtime. This would be faster than not optimizing, but slower than the first test. Since it's a literal the compiled version is static.

Comment: The [MDN Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) explicitly recommends the use of literals. _Regular expression literals provide compilation of the regular expression when the script is loaded. When the regular expression will remain constant, use this for better performance._ Which is it?