# Why JavaScript regex literal execution is slower when it is assigned to a variable?

Tags: javascript, regex, performance

My question is related to a previous [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312976/when-are-javascript-regular-expression-literals-compiled), which says the following two ways have almost the same speed.

But when I test it actually using loop count 1000000, there seems to be a consistent performance. While I expect Example 1 should be faster, but it turns out to be slower than Example 2.

The results of the testing page are [here](https://jsperf.com/testecompilation/1). For example 1, the execution times are: [20.27,19.82, 16.17], but for example 2, they are less:[18.57, 15.48, 15.14].

The results confuse me a lot. Could anyone have a hint about the reason?

```
var str = "Hello World";
// Example 1
var regExp1 = /[aeiou]+/gi;
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
  regExp1.exec(str);
// Example 2
for(var j = 0; j < 1000; ++j)
  /[aeiou]+/gi.exec(str);
```

Comment: How are you timing this?  I think for the benchmark to be meaningful, it should only be measuring the calls to `exec()`, and not anything else (the "anything else" not being relevant to the performance of the regex).

Comment: The [link](https://jsperf.com/testecompilation/1) that you've provided for conducting the tests measures Operations/sec and not time elapsed. When I ran the tests, I found that the ops/sec is more for Example 1 than Example 2 which means that method in Example 1 is actually faster than method in Example 2.

Answer (score 1):

This is an extended test for the original question (with times from one of my runs, first time is for "Hello World!", the second with "a")

```
let str = "Hello World!"; // Alternative "a" 

// Literal in loop         (392 ms, 384 ms)
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    for(let j = 0; j < 1000; ++j)
        /[aeiou]+/gi.exec(str);
}

// Construction in loop    (1747 ms, 1677 ms)
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    for(let j = 0; j < 1000; ++j)
        new RegExp("[aeiou]+", "gi").exec(str);
}

// Cached literal          (335 ms, 252 ms, fastest)
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    let regex = /[aeiou]+/gi;
    for(let j = 0; j < 1000; ++j)
        regex.exec(str);
}

// Cached construction     (351 ms, 270 ms)
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    let regex = new RegExp("[aeiou]+", "gi");
    for(let j = 0; j < 1000; ++j)
        regex.exec(str);
}
```

So we can observe that

- the literal is always faster than the constructor version:
- the cached version is always faster than the inline version
- the difference between the literal inside the loop and the literal outside the loop is small compared to the construction inside the loop
- the overhead of the literal in the loop is so small that it only is relevant with many iterations on short strings (readability vs runtime performance in more complex cases)

This observation could partially be explained by the following paragraph from [the MDN RegExp reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Description):

> The literal notation provides a compilation of the regular expression when the expression is evaluated. Use literal notation when the regular expression will remain constant. For example, if you use literal notation to construct a regular expression used in a loop, the regular expression won't be recompiled on each iteration.

It seems that while all literals are compiled during loading it is still necessary to construct an RegExp object from the compiled literal which causes the overhead of the literal in the loop which is small compared to the runtime compilation with the constructor in the loop

Answer (score 0):

It must be slower.

Because every time you go in a new iteration in the loop you re-evaluate the regex before executing it.

This causes a small delay but with large loops, there will be a time difference

In the 1st example, it is already defined and evaluated.

Hence, the only time needed is for the execution.

Answer (score 0):

[jsperf.com](https://jsperf.com/testecompilation/1) is showing **ops/sec**, not execution times. Thus the higher the value, the faster the code.

The first version is faster, not slower. You got confusing results by running different number of iterations in one test set. **20.27** ops/s is faster than **18.57** ops/s.

There is no question - caching the regexp in a separate variable is going to be faster than compiling it in each iteration (the V8 VM caches compiled regex'es but apparently not as efficiently as doing it explicitly).